# Why sub resources need to be prepended with resource in URI?

Tags: api, rest

Having a doubt on REST API URI design.

Let's consider each Post has one or more tags. So, a tag could be retrieved by

```
GET /posts/1/tags/1
```

Tags are stored uniquely in DB with an ID. So I could access full detail of a tag using

```
GET /tags/1
```

If Post information needed, then I could use query parameter

```
GET /tags/1?post=1
```

My question is why the first format widely suggested over second/third format.

Suggest me use case/scenario to prefer first format or complications with second/third format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the first format widely suggested over second/third format.

This is not the case. The three are used for different things.

You must first ask **if a tag can exist without a post**. I'd say **yes**. Because of this, the **second form**

```
GET /tags/1
```

is a good URI to get the representation of a tag.

Next, ask yourself **if a post can have multiple tags**. I'd again say **yes**. Because of this the **first form** is a good way to get a specific tag of a post. More general, the form

```
GET /posts/1/tags
```

returns all tags that are used for post `1`. This is a **collection** resource. One of those tags is tag `1` which *can* be navigated to by

```
GET /posts/1/tags/1
```

Note that the first and the second form both identify tag `1`. **Both** forms can be used at the same time.

The **third form** makes no sense at all. Query parameters after the `?` like `post=1` are generally used to **filter a collection resource**. One could say: "Give me all tags that are used on posts `1`, `23`, and `42`. This could be formulated as

```
GET /tags?post=1,23,42
```

Here we filter the collection resource of all tags by a condition.

Your third form uses a query parameter `post=1` **on a single resource**. But it makes no sense to filter a single tag.

A **fourth form** could be useful: Give me all posts that use a tag:

```
GET /tags/1/posts
```

This would return the collection resource of all posts that use tag `1`.

And even a **fith form** with the same meaning as fourth would be possible:

```
GET /posts?tag=1
```

**Summary:**

When thinking about REST URIs, think about resources. What are your resource? What are the relations between them? Can one type of resource exist only "inside" another type of resource (a hotel room can only exist inside a hotel) or can it exist on its own (a tag can exist even if not post is tagged with it). What could be a subresource of another resource? What collection resources exist? How can they be filtered?

Comment: Yes, agree with your thoughts. /tags?post=1 vs /posts/1/tags. Both are same. Which one I have to pick?  I am fan of second format but arguably first one also make sense. These perceptions differ based on individual. There are no rules in REST API world rather best practices/perceptions exists. @Tichodroma